# Google Apps Script does not recognize tables in my document

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-api, google-docs

First of all, I would like to thank you for your help in solving problems prior to this project, which was of great value in solving past problems.
I'm working with google apps script to format the titles of a document within tables.
The normal text is this:
[image: normal text title 1]

After the script runs it looks like this:
[image: custom title 1]

The script is inserting the text inside tables in a normal way, as desired, however in addition to this formatting, I need to style the titles. Example: Title 1 usually has an Arial 18 font, without boldface and I want to change that to a Roboto 18 font with boldface.
I tried to work with custom styles of google apps, but in the script processing the formatting is lost specifically when it passes through this line of code.
[image: fragment code 1]

I have already tried to recover the tables and format them after the update process, but the system does not recognize the tables as tables after the update process, and only the last formatted title remains in the desired format, as shown in the second image. See some prints of my debugging process.
The first title is changed and placed within the table and the formatting is applied and the inserted table is recognized:
[image: first text custom title]
[image: debug 1]
When the script reaches the saveAndClose () point of the second method, the customization of the previous title disappears:
[image: previous title does not persist customization]
At the end of the process, only the last customized title remains in the desired format.
I already tried to recover the inserted tables to perform the update in the style of the text of the second column, but the script does not recognize the tables. It recognizes only one, and in fact, in this document I have 4 tables.
[image: End of document processing]
[image: End of script processing]

Here is a script for verification:

```js
function verifiStyle(){
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var paragrafs = body.getParagraphs();
  
  for(var i = paragrafs.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    var attr = paragrafs[i].getAttributes();
    
    for(var at in attr){
      if(at == "HEADING" & attr[at] == "HEADING1"){
        VerifTitle1(i);
      }
      else if(at == "HEADING" & attr[at] == "HEADING2"){
        VerifTitle2(i);
      }
      else if(at == "HEADING" & attr[at] == "HEADING3"){
        VerifTitle3(i);
      }
      else if(at == "HEADING" & attr[at] == "HEADING4"){
        VerifTitle4(i);
      }
      else if(at == "HEADING" & attr[at] == "NORMAL"){
        VerifTextoNormal(i);
      }
    }
  }
  var tables = body.getTables();
}

function VerifTitle1(value){
   var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  
  var texto = body.getChild(value);
  var ttt = texto.getText();
  
  var cells = [
      ['', '']
    ];
  
  var styleCell1 = {};
    styleCell1[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 20;
    styleCell1[DocumentApp.Attribute.VERTICAL_ALIGNMENT] = DocumentApp.VerticalAlignment.CENTER;
    styleCell1[DocumentApp.Attribute.FOREGROUND_COLOR]='#888888';
    styleCell1[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY]='Roboto';
    
    var styleCell = {};
    styleCell[DocumentApp.Attribute.VERTICAL_ALIGNMENT] = DocumentApp.VerticalAlignment.CENTER;
    styleCell[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY]='Roboto';
    styleCell[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 18;
    styleCell[DocumentApp.Attribute.FOREGROUND_COLOR]='#000000';
    styleCell[DocumentApp.Attribute.HEIGHT] = 0.5;
  
  body.removeChild(body.getChild(value));
  var table = body.insertTable(value, cells);
  
    table.getRow(0).getCell(1).appendParagraph(ttt).setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING2);
    table.getRow(0).getCell(1).setAttributes(styleCell);
    table.getRow(0).getCell(0).setWidth(2);
    table.getRow(0).getCell(0).setAttributes(styleCell1);
    table.setBorderColor('#ffffff');
  table.getRow(0).editAsText().setBold(true);
    
    const index = body.getChildIndex(table);
    const documentId = doc.getId();
    doc.saveAndClose();
    const tableStart = Docs.Documents.get(documentId).body.content[index + 1].startIndex;
    const tempStyle = {width: {magnitude :0, unit: "PT"}, dashStyle: "SOLID", color: {color: {rgbColor: {blue: 0}}}};
    const resource = {requests: [
      {updateTableCellStyle: {
        tableStartLocation: {index: tableStart},
        tableCellStyle: {borderTop: tempStyle, borderBottom: tempStyle, borderLeft: tempStyle, borderRight: tempStyle},
        fields: "borderTop,borderBottom,borderLeft,borderRight"
      }},
      {updateTableCellStyle: {
        tableRange: {
          tableCellLocation: {tableStartLocation: {index: tableStart}, rowIndex: 0, columnIndex: 0}, rowSpan: 1, columnSpan: 1},
        tableCellStyle: {
          borderRight: {dashStyle: "SOLID", width: {magnitude: 3, unit: "PT"}, color: {color: {rgbColor: {red: 0.9372549019607843, green: 0.3254901960784314, blue: 0.3137254901960784}}}}
        },
        fields: "borderRight"
      }}
    ]};
    Docs.Documents.batchUpdate(resource, documentId);
  
  table = body.getChild(value).asTable();
}

function VerifTitle2(value){
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  
  var texto = body.getChild(value);
  var ttt = texto.getText();
  
  var cells = [
      ['', '']
    ];
  
  var styleCell1 = {};
    styleCell1[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 18;
    styleCell1[DocumentApp.Attribute.VERTICAL_ALIGNMENT] = DocumentApp.VerticalAlignment.CENTER;
    styleCell1[DocumentApp.Attribute.FOREGROUND_COLOR]='#888888';
    styleCell1[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY]='Roboto';
    
    var styleCell = {};
    styleCell[DocumentApp.Attribute.VERTICAL_ALIGNMENT] = DocumentApp.VerticalAlignment.CENTER;
    styleCell[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY]='Roboto';
    styleCell[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 15;
    styleCell[DocumentApp.Attribute.FOREGROUND_COLOR]='#000000';
    styleCell[DocumentApp.Attribute.HEIGHT] = 0.5;
  
  body.removeChild(body.getChild(value));
  var table = body.insertTable(value, cells);
  
    table.getRow(0).getCell(1).appendParagraph(ttt).setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING2);
    table.getRow(0).getCell(1).setAttributes(styleCell);
    table.getRow(0).getCell(0).setWidth(2);
    table.getRow(0).getCell(0).setAttributes(styleCell1);
    table.setBorderColor('#ffffff');
  table.getRow(0).editAsText().setBold(true);
    
    const index = body.getChildIndex(table);
    const documentId = doc.getId();
    doc.saveAndClose();
    const tableStart = Docs.Documents.get(documentId).body.content[index + 1].startIndex;
    const tempStyle = {width: {magnitude :0, unit: "PT"}, dashStyle: "SOLID", color: {color: {rgbColor: {blue: 0}}}};
    const resource = {requests: [
      {updateTableCellStyle: {
        tableStartLocation: {index: tableStart},
        tableCellStyle: {borderTop: tempStyle, borderBottom: tempStyle, borderLeft: tempStyle, borderRight: tempStyle},
        fields: "borderTop,borderBottom,borderLeft,borderRight"
      }},
      {updateTableCellStyle: {
        tableRange: {
          tableCellLocation: {tableStartLocation: {index: tableStart}, rowIndex: 0, columnIndex: 0}, rowSpan: 1, columnSpan: 1},
        tableCellStyle: {
          borderRight: {dashStyle: "SOLID", width: {magnitude: 3, unit: "PT"}, color: {color: {rgbColor: {red: 0.9372549019607843, green: 0.3254901960784314, blue: 0.3137254901960784}}}}
        },
        fields: "borderRight"
      }}
    ]};
    Docs.Documents.batchUpdate(resource, documentId);
}

function VerifTitle3(value){
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  
  var texto = body.getChild(value);
  var ttt = texto.getText();
  
  var cells = [
      ['', '']
    ];
  
  var styleCell1 = {};
    styleCell1[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 16;
    styleCell1[DocumentApp.Attribute.VERTICAL_ALIGNMENT] = DocumentApp.VerticalAlignment.CENTER;
    styleCell1[DocumentApp.Attribute.FOREGROUND_COLOR]='#888888';
    styleCell1[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY]='Roboto';
    
    var styleCell = {};
    styleCell[DocumentApp.Attribute.VERTICAL_ALIGNMENT] = DocumentApp.VerticalAlignment.CENTER;
    styleCell[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY]='Roboto';
    styleCell[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 14;
    styleCell[DocumentApp.Attribute.FOREGROUND_COLOR]='#000000';
    styleCell[DocumentApp.Attribute.HEIGHT] = 0.5;
  styleCell[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = true;
  
  body.removeChild(body.getChild(value));
  var table = body.insertTable(value, cells);
  
    table.getRow(0).getCell(1).appendParagraph(ttt).setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING3);
    table.getRow(0).getCell(1).setAttributes(styleCell);
    table.getRow(0).getCell(0).setWidth(2);
    table.getRow(0).getCell(0).setAttributes(styleCell1);
    table.setBorderColor('#ffffff');
  table.getRow(0).editAsText().setBold(true);
    
    const index = body.getChildIndex(table);
    const documentId = doc.getId();
    doc.saveAndClose();
    const tableStart = Docs.Documents.get(documentId).body.content[index + 1].startIndex;
    const tempStyle = {width: {magnitude :0, unit: "PT"}, dashStyle: "SOLID", color: {color: {rgbColor: {blue: 0}}}};
    const resource = {requests: [
      {updateTableCellStyle: {
        tableStartLocation: {index: tableStart},
        tableCellStyle: {borderTop: tempStyle, borderBottom: tempStyle, borderLeft: tempStyle, borderRight: tempStyle},
        fields: "borderTop,borderBottom,borderLeft,borderRight"
      }},
      {updateTableCellStyle: {
        tableRange: {
          tableCellLocation: {tableStartLocation: {index: tableStart}, rowIndex: 0, columnIndex: 0}, rowSpan: 1, columnSpan: 1},
        tableCellStyle: {
          borderRight: {dashStyle: "SOLID", width: {magnitude: 3, unit: "PT"}, color: {color: {rgbColor: {red: 0.9372549019607843, green: 0.3254901960784314, blue: 0.3137254901960784}}}}
        },
        fields: "borderRight"
      }}
    ]};
    Docs.Documents.batchUpdate(resource, documentId);
}

function VerifTitle4(value){
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  
  var texto = body.getChild(value);
  var ttt = texto.getText();
  
  var cells = [
      ['', '']
    ];
  
  var styleCell1 = {};
    styleCell1[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 14;
    styleCell1[DocumentApp.Attribute.VERTICAL_ALIGNMENT] = DocumentApp.VerticalAlignment.CENTER;
    styleCell1[DocumentApp.Attribute.FOREGROUND_COLOR]='#888888';
    styleCell1[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY]='Roboto';
    
    var styleCell = {};
    styleCell[DocumentApp.Attribute.VERTICAL_ALIGNMENT] = DocumentApp.VerticalAlignment.CENTER;
    styleCell[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY]='Roboto';
    styleCell[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 12;
    styleCell[DocumentApp.Attribute.FOREGROUND_COLOR]='#000000';
    styleCell[DocumentApp.Attribute.HEIGHT] = 0.5;
  
  body.removeChild(body.getChild(value));
  var table = body.insertTable(value, cells);
  
  var tables = body.getTables();
  
    table.getRow(0).getCell(1).appendParagraph(ttt).setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING2);
    table.getRow(0).getCell(1).setAttributes(styleCell);
    table.getRow(0).getCell(0).setWidth(2);
    table.getRow(0).getCell(0).setAttributes(styleCell1);
    table.setBorderColor('#ffffff');
  table.getRow(0).editAsText().setBold(true);
    
    const index = body.getChildIndex(table);
    const documentId = doc.getId();
    doc.saveAndClose();
    const tableStart = Docs.Documents.get(documentId).body.content[index + 1].startIndex;
    const tempStyle = {width: {magnitude :0, unit: "PT"}, dashStyle: "SOLID", color: {color: {rgbColor: {blue: 0}}}};
    const resource = {requests: [
      {updateTableCellStyle: {
        tableStartLocation: {index: tableStart},
        tableCellStyle: {borderTop: tempStyle, borderBottom: tempStyle, borderLeft: tempStyle, borderRight: tempStyle},
        fields: "borderTop,borderBottom,borderLeft,borderRight"
      }},
      {updateTableCellStyle: {
        tableRange: {
          tableCellLocation: {tableStartLocation: {index: tableStart}, rowIndex: 0, columnIndex: 0}, rowSpan: 1, columnSpan: 1},
        tableCellStyle: {
          borderRight: {dashStyle: "SOLID", width: {magnitude: 3, unit: "PT"}, color: {color: {rgbColor: {red: 0.9372549019607843, green: 0.3254901960784314, blue: 0.3137254901960784}}}}
        },
        fields: "borderRight"
      }}
    ]};
    Docs.Documents.batchUpdate(resource, documentId);
  var tables1 = body.getTables();
}

function VerifTextoNormal(value){
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  
  var para = body.getParagraphs();
  
  var styleCell = {};
    styleCell[DocumentApp.Attribute.HEADING] = DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.NORMAL;
    styleCell[DocumentApp.Attribute.VERTICAL_ALIGNMENT] = DocumentApp.VerticalAlignment.CENTER;
    styleCell[DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT] = DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.JUSTIFY;
    styleCell[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY]='Arial';
    styleCell[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 12;
    styleCell[DocumentApp.Attribute.FOREGROUND_COLOR]='#000000';
    styleCell[DocumentApp.Attribute.INDENT_FIRST_LINE] = 15;
  
  para[value].setAttributes(styleCell);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried [re-opening](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#saveandclose) the Doc after the saveClose by getting the Doc Id again?. Is it really necessary to do the `saveAndClose`?

Comment: SaveAndClose is really necessary, because without it the update just doesn't work. This suggestion to reopen and retrieve the id and make changes, I have also tried. The point is that as I said, the script does not recognize my tables as tables.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot still replicate your situation. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. In order to replicate yout issue and think of the solution, can you provide the sample Document for replicating your issue?

Comment: Greetings @Tanaike. The link to my document is this (https://docs.google.com/document/d/1tk-eeaBSSJ9Im2b5Y-e1jL8t18rKFXhp356udoyx8wA/edit?usp=sharing). I thank you for your help.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding the information. When I tested it, I could confirm the same issue. So I proposed a workaround as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this answer?

#### Issue and workaround:

I could confirm the same issue using your shared sample Google Document. In this case, after `updateTables()` was finished, it seems that `getTables()` doesn't return the tables in the Document body. I think that this might be a bug. I thought that this might also affect to the current issue. So, in order to avoid this issue, I would like to propose to use Docs API.

At your script, when `verifiStyle()` is run, it updates the tables at the last line of `verifiStyle()`. This is a workaround.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, please modify as follows.

From:

This is the script in the last line of the function `verifiStyle()`.

```
  var tables = body.getTables();
}
```

To:

```
  updateTables();  // Modified
}

// Added the below function.
function updateTables() {
  const docId = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getId();
  const contents = Docs.Documents.get(docId).body.content;
  const reqs = contents.reduce((ar, e) => {
    if ("table" in e) {
      const t = e.table.tableRows[0].tableCells;
      const obj = [
        {updateTextStyle: {
          range: {startIndex: t[0].startIndex, endIndex: t[0].endIndex},
          textStyle: {bold: true, fontSize: {magnitude: 20, unit: "PT"}, weightedFontFamily: {fontFamily: "Roboto"}},fields: "bold,fontSize,weightedFontFamily"}
        },
        {updateTextStyle: {
          range: {startIndex: t[1].startIndex, endIndex: t[1].endIndex},
          textStyle: {bold: true, fontSize: {magnitude: 18, unit: "PT"}, weightedFontFamily: {fontFamily: "Roboto"}}, fields: "bold,fontSize,weightedFontFamily"}
        }
      ];
      ar = [...ar, obj];
    }
    return ar;
  }, []);
  Docs.Documents.batchUpdate({requests: reqs}, docId);
}
```

#### References:

- [Method: documents.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate)
- [UpdateTextStyleRequest](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#updatetextstylerequest)

Comment: After a few tweaks to the original code you provided me, my script is finally doing exactly what I need. Thank you!

Comment: @Leonardo Silva Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.